# My C program does not run

Tags: c

I am not a C enthusiast and I am writing this, grudgingly, as a part of my assignment. The program is to input two polynomials and to add them and display them. I wrote modules to input and display however the program does not run.

In `Dev-C++` it says I have multiple definitions of main.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>


// This is my implementation to add and multiply
// two polynomials using linked list
// So far, it just inputs and displays the polynomial
struct term {
    int exp;
    int coef;
    struct term *next;
};

struct term* addTerm(struct term *polynomial,int exp,int coef){ // adds a term to polynomial
    if(polynomial == NULL ){
        polynomial = (struct term *)malloc(sizeof(struct term));
        polynomial->exp = exp;
        polynomial->coef = coef;
    }else{
        struct term *newTerm = (struct term *)malloc(sizeof(struct term));
        newTerm->exp = exp;
        newTerm->coef = coef;
        polynomial->next = newTerm;
    }
    return polynomial;
}

void display(struct term *polynomial){ // displays the polynomial
    struct term *p = polynomial;
    while(p->next != NULL){
        printf("+ %dx%d",p->coef,p->exp); p = p->next;
    }
}

void main(){ // run it
    int i = 5;
    int coef = 0;
    int exp = 0;
    struct term *polynomial = NULL;
    while(i++ < 5){
        printf("Enter CoEfficient and Exponent for Term %d",i);
        scanf("%d %d",&coef,&exp);
        polynomial = addTerm(polynomial,exp,coef);
    }
    display(polynomial);
    getch();
}
```

How do I get it to run ?

Comment: Is that the *only* error you get? Do you somehow have the same file in your project twice? Or multiple sources with a `main` function in each?

Comment: You can only have one `main` in an entire C program, including all `.c` modules. `main` is THE entry point for the whole program. Also, the `while` loop in main will not execute since `i` is already not `< 5`. Maybe you did that for debug purposes...

Comment: Your `display` function doesn't check for a NULL `polynomial` so it will segfault at the `p->next != NULL` if `p` itself is `NULL`.

Comment: `void main()` is incorrect; it should be `int main(void)`. Where did you learn the `void main()` form? (That's not a rhetorical question; I'd really like to know where you learned that.)

Comment: @KeithThompson That is what I learnt in school. Somehow it runs there.

Comment: @LittleChild: I'm not surprised that it "works"; a lot of things in C are errors that the compiler isn't required to complain about. `void main()` is one of those errors. You've been taught incorrectly by someone who apparently doesn't know any better. Read [this link](http://www.c-faq.com/ansi/voidmain.html) (and browse the rest of that site as well). I'll leave it to you to decide whether to show that link to your instructor.

Comment: Please copy the log from "Compile Log" (seen at the underside of the screen) and paste it here. Also, make sure you update Dev-C++ to version 5.4.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess, you have several `.c` files in your IDE project, with more than one containing a `main()` function. Alternatively -- if your IDE permits it -- you may have added the same `.c` file to the project more than once.

Comment: Yes, I do have another test `.c` file with main in it. Is that not allowed ? Sorry, I am a Java programmer.

Comment: @LittleChild: I don't know how your IDE manages projects, but you generally have one `main()` per project, and everything in the project is compiled and linked together.

Comment: I want to use `Dev-C++` for my assignments. How do I manage multiple files with `main()`. I mean, I do not want to create multiple projects for every program :)

Comment: @LittleChil on a not exactly subtle side note, don't try to compile C code as if it was C++.

Comment: @H2CO3 Can you please run my program ? It stops abruptly and there is no error message in it.

Comment: @LittleChild: There are multiple bugs in your addTerm which, seeing that this is an assignment, I'll let you to figure out yourself.

Comment: @H2CO3 IDE does not point out what they are. A little help will be appreciated

Comment: @LittleChild see the comments I posted to your original post. Also, you can't have more than one entry point to a program. Thus, you can only have one `main`. You can have multiple `.c` files. They don't all have to have a `main`. Only one should.

Comment: @mbratch I fixed that. Program runs but stops abruptly. IDE compiles successfully and I do not understand why it compiles if there are multiple errors in it. I sincerely apologize if I am wasting your time :)

Comment: @LittleChild: The program stops abruptly because of bugs. You need to figure out what those bugs are, and fix them. The compiler won't do that for you.

Comment: @LittleChild if you fixed it then you need to show your updated code. Please edit your original post accordingly.

Comment: @NPE At least hint to me where they are .. if not what they are

Comment: @mbratch oops at making `int i = 5`. It was supposed to be zero. Added a conditional in `display()` to see if `polynomial` is `null`. Anything else, sir ?

Comment: @LittleChild your `addTerm` needs to set `next` to `NULL` in your first `if` clause (when `polynomial` is initially `NULL`).

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of all files with similar names to this same file by appending a unique numeric character at the end of each one before the `.c`

Open up a terminal and change your cwd to the directory of the project src folder.
Type the following command to compile the code:
`gcc -W -o polynomial test.c`

Run the code now by typing the following:
`./polynomial`

Post your results here if you are still having problems with it

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma DONT include <conio.h>


// This is my implementation to add and multiply
// two polynomials using linked list
// So far, it just inputs and displays the polynomial
struct term {
    struct term *next;
    int exp;
    int coef;
};

struct term *addTerm(struct term **polynomial, int exp, int coef){ // adds a term to polynomial

     struct term *newTerm;
     newTerm = malloc(sizeof *newTerm);
     newTerm->exp = exp;
     newTerm->coef = coef;

#if APPEND_AT_TAIL
     for (; *polynomial;polynomial = &(*polynomial)->next) {;}
     newTerm->next = NULL;
#else
     newTerm->next = *polynomial;
#endif
    *polynomial = newTerm ;

    return newTerm;
}

void display(struct term *polynomial){ // displays the polynomial
    struct term *p;
    for( p = polynomial; p; p = p->next ){
        printf("+ {%d * %d}", p->coef, p->exp);
    }
}

int main(void){ // run it
    int i ;
    int coef = 0;
    int exp = 0;
    struct term *polynomial = NULL;

    for(i=0; i < 5; i++){
      printf("Enter CoEfficient and Exponent for Term %d> ", i);
      scanf("%d %d",&coef,&exp);
      addTerm( &polynomial, exp, coef);
  }
  display(polynomial);
  // getch();
  return 0;
}
```